play.google badge url adds 18 cookies?
Im adding a button with the google play badge image that I have generated using their own tool. But when I do so it adds 18 different cookies. I can't figure out why.
When I run Lighthouse it complains about the use of 3rd party cookies.
When I remove below code and refresh the page all of the below 18 cookies go away.
Is there any way of using the badge image without it adds all the cookies?
Button code:
<Button
    className="h-fit w-[208px] bg-transparent p-0 shadow-none"
    onPress={() => handleOnStoreClick('google')}>
      <Image
        className="h-auto w-full"
        width={208}
        height={80.48}
        loading="lazy"
        alt="Get it on Google Play"
        src={`https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/${i18n.resolvedLanguage?.toString().slice(0, 2).toLocaleLowerCase() || 'en'}_badge_web_generic.png`}/>
</Button>




I ended upp downloading the badges and hosted them myself instead
